# Proposed tag synonyms: lexical-analyser & lexical-analyzer

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I don't have the rep in either area (nor will I ever), but these two are synonyms:

- [lexical-analyzer](/questions/tagged/lexical-analyzer)
- [lexical-analyser](/questions/tagged/lexical-analyser)

Comment: 3 vs. 74... let's manually retag the 74!

Comment: Hmm, such a colourful action might offend those who favour a different spelling, especially the Commonwealthers (or Commonwealthy?).

Comment: There's also `lexical-analysis`, with 45 questions, and `lexer` with 143.

Comment: True, though I would say that one describes a program or function, the other might describe an activity undertaken by the function.